# Facebook API. Get count of Published Posts

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API of Facebook version 2.8 and after research almost the whole www, can't find the way to get the count of published posts in the last month on my fan page (I have all the perms).

Comment: It's a simple question. Not about code failing or different behavior, it's about get a value in the FB Graph API. Not hard to understand I need to get # of posts published in a Fan Page through the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

I had to obtain the last month posts. It's easy if you have less than 100, the limit that FB sets. It's not my case so I run a while with an algortihm until the last post of the month is counted.

It's not a clean solution, but I still can't believe why facebook doesn't provide this common and needed data.